# Nested action makes reducer state different from redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a problem where my redux store differs from my state in my reducer. The problem has something to do with how I am calling my actions. My goal is to get the updated state so I can call it within the reducer for a different case (ex. `state.numbers`). I call an action on a button press. This action has its properties that get sent to a different reducer and then calls a function (this function dispatches the action that is causing issues).

Here is that action called on a button press:

```
export const startReminder = (item) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ //this dispatch works great and isn't the issue
      type: START_REMINDER,
      id: item.id
    });
    scheduleNotification.startReminder(item); //the issue is this function right here
  };
};
```

This function I will simplify to just this because it reproduces the issue:

```
export const scheduleNotification = {
  async startReminder() {
    store.dispatch(testing(1));
  }
};
```

The testing action that gets dispatched looks like this:

```
export const testing = (number) => {
  return {
    type: 'testing',
    number
  };
};
```

Then in my reducer I press a different button which triggers a case to log `state.numbers`. If I trigger this case in the same session I added a number (or multiple), they will not get logged. But if I reload the session and then have the state log it (I persist the data), it correctly logs it to the console. I tried moving this dispatched action out of the start reminder and that fixed the issue. So it has something to do with being called in a helper function getting called in another action.

I wish I could move it but it isn't that simple. In the scheduleNotification function, I get a unique ID that I need to store in the store. I can't dispatch the action until I have that ID. If anyone knows what's wrong or has any advice I would really appreciate it, I have no idea what is causing this issue.

An example, say my numbers array is empty and then I add a number to it. Even though I see it in the redux store, if log during the same session it was added, it will come up as an empty array. Say I add a number and then reload the application and then log the state. This time it will show the number in it properly.

Comment: In what way is `startReminder` async? Do you need to `await` the call to get an id? Also, the `store.dispatch` seems off, shouldn't happen in an action creator. But maybe you added this just for debugging?

Comment: startReminder is async because in the code I didn't include (doesn't cause problem) I have to await for a notificationID to be returned. Then I want to call ```store.dispatch()``` and use that ID and add it to my reducer. Why is the ```store.dispatch``` off? That must be the issue then

Comment: The `store.dispatch` seems off because you could just use `dispatch` directly. I'm assuming `startReminder` is a thunk action. Do you want to dispatch `START_REMINDER` before or after you've waited for `scheduleNotification` to do its async operation?

Comment: Before for sure. The start reminder action will affect the screen. The scheduleNotification is a backend thing so the app keeps track of all of their notifications.

Comment: Ok I hope I understood your context correctly, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export const startReminder = (item) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: START_REMINDER,
      id: item.id
    });

    // This is where the request to your backend happens.
    // startReminder needs to return a promise or be async itself
    const number = await scheduleNotification.startReminder(item);

    // Since a request can fail, you would normally have error handling here,
    // like a try {} catch {} block, but I left that out for the sake of simplicity.

    dispatch({
        type: 'testing',
        number,
    });
  };
};
```

Comment: Yes this solved it! Thank you so much I had been stuck on this for over a week. You are the man. Any chance you could explain why dispatching directly from the store was bugging everything?

Comment: You're welcome. Not sure why your `store.dispatch` didn't work, might depend on your actual code. But generally, thunks are written the way I posted.